# How to combine a hierarchical date and time index into a single datetime index in Pandas?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
                     temp
2014-11-20 12:45:00        51
2014-11-20 12:46:00        43
2014-11-20 12:47:00        44
2014-11-21 12:45:00        44
2014-11-21 12:46:00        46
2014-11-21 12:47:00        48
2014-11-22 12:45:00        38
2014-11-22 12:46:00        32
2014-11-22 12:47:00        37
```

If you copy the above and use `pd.read_clipboard()` I believe you should get a hierarchical index (or MultiIndex)

The first index is the date and the second index is the time as strings.  How can I combine the two indexes into a single datetime index?

(Note this is not about using `pd.read_csv()` `parse_dates` option because the dataframe is not coming from a csv file, the question is how to do it with an existing dataframe.)

Comment: The date and time levels, are it strings or datetime.date/time objects?

Comment: @joris: they are currently strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) method to parse strings to datetime values. To use this, I think the easiest is to first just concatenate the date and time strings leading to a single level string index:

```
In [184]: s
Out[184]:
                     temp
2014-11-20 12:45:00    51
           12:46:00    43
           12:47:00    44
2014-11-21 12:45:00    44
           12:46:00    46
           12:47:00    48
2014-11-22 12:45:00    38
           12:46:00    32
           12:47:00    37

In [187]: s.index = s.index.get_level_values(0).values + ' ' + s.index.get_level_values(1)

In [188]: s.index
Out[188]: Index([u'2014-11-20 12:45:00', u'2014-11-20 12:46:00', ... u'2014-11-22 12:47:00'], dtype='object')
```

And then you can use `to_datetime` to convert the strings to a DatetimeIndex:

```
In [189]: s.index = pd.to_datetime(s.index)

In [190]: s.index
Out[190]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-11-20 12:45:00, ..., 2014-11-22 12:47:00]
Length: 9, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```